# How can I change the picture used by this AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, desktop

I am using this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to 
    set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Earth Horizon.jpg"'
```

to set the desktop on a lab of computers. How can I select a different picture instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the images in that folder by opening a Finder window,  pressing <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd>, and entering the folder name `/Library/Desktop Pictures`; or by running `ls '/Library/Desktop Pictures'` in Terminal.

```
pse@Mithos:~$ ls '/Library/Desktop Pictures'
Abstract/                   Desert 4.jpg                Galaxy.jpg                  Reflection 1.jpg
Abstract 1.jpg              Desert 5.jpg                Grass Blades.jpg            Reflection 2.jpg
Abstract 2.jpg              Desert 6.jpg                Hawaiian Print.jpg          Reflection 3.jpg
Abstract 3.jpg              Desert 7.jpg                High Sierra.jpg             Reflection 4.jpg
...
```

Choose one of the images and then put its name in the place of `Earth Horizon.jpg` in your script like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to 
    set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/FILE_NAME_HERE.jpg"'
```